# How to crop part of gif image?

Tags: c#, .net, image, pixel, crop

*Hi every one,*

i wrote some code to crop large image to small one.

Everything is OK but when i tried GIF images i get the following exception

"**A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format.**"

I'm using Graphics class to do this

```
Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(croppedBitmap)
```

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pixels of GIF images are not RGB values, they are indexes of a color table array stored in the header of the file. Graphic objects only support non-indexed pixel format.
If you want to use the Graphic object, you must convert your image into a non-indexed pixel format.

This is exactly what this guy did: 
 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WriteTextToGif.aspx?display=PrintAll

Comment: Thank u;

But i want to do this without changing the image type and resolution.!

Comment: Then I would do the work with a Bitmap object:
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight);
Bitmap cropped = bitmap.Clone(rect, bitmap.PixelFormat);
return cropped;